# Bit stuck on finding the largest possible value under a limit

Tags: python, algorithm, function, logic

I've been working on a [Code Wars function](https://www.codewars.com/kata/628e6f112324192c65cd8c97)

```
def prescribe(d, a, b):
```

Where the attempt is that given a target number d, say 4540, I want to calculate how close the number a, say 9, can get without exceeding the value. Alongside a bunch of other criteria. This is the working I have created so far:

```
sum = 0
x = int(d / a) * a
y = int(d / b) * b

if d % a == 0:
    return x
elif d % b == 0:
    return y
while d > sum:
    sum += a + b
final = sum - (a + b)

if x > final and x > y:
    return x
elif y > final and y > sum:
    return y
else:
    return final
```

It's not the most efficient code admittedly, so bear with me. The main issue occurring here is that I can't quite seem to figure out how I can return the maximum possible value within the target d. So for instance when I call the function with the following parameters:

```
prescribe(4540, 9, 15)
```

The maximum value I return is with the number 9: 4536 when in actuality the answer is 4539.
What I assume is the issue is the fact that I'm getting around the maximum possible value by simply dividing 4540 with 9, and then converting 504.4 into 504.0 with the int() function. When in reality I should be using 504.3.

I hope this illustrates the shortcoming I'm facing with my code—can't seem to figure out how I can get the maximum possible value within the target range. If anyone could advise me as to the limitation or way I should approach this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: *"Alongside a bunch of other criteria."* Those criteria should be in the question itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hint you need to use all combination fo ax+by<=d where 1<x,y<d//a, d//b, and answer would be ax+by which should be most closed to d, in given example, 9x+15y  and 1<x<4540//9, 1<y<4540//15 , use for loop for x, y value in above equation and fill it in equation and find the vbalue that is closed to 4540

Comment: @user3386109 Sorry, I'd provided the link to the question since it contains the run-down of the criterias but the basic gyst of it is:

Calculate the closest value of A under D.
Calculate the closest value of B under D.
And then calculate the largest value of the sums of A+D under D. Whichever one of these is the largest possible value under the target, that is to be the assigned output. i hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One string solution

```
def prescribe(d, a, b):
    return d - min((d - a * i) % b for i in range(d // a + 1))


print(prescribe(4540, 9, 15))  # 4539
```

**Explanation**

So lets rephrase this task to

Find minimum r for `a*x + b*y + r = d`, where `d`, `a`, `b` are given parameters and `x`, `y` are variables

Solution for that is

1. You have to iterate over every possible `x` (or `y`), but as far as `a` is positive you only have to iterate over `[0, d//a]` interval.
2. Count `r = (d - a * x) % b`
3. Find minimum between all the `r`s you recieved

Comment: are you sure this is correct? failing for prescribe(4540, 312, 752) answer should be 4384, there should be atleast 1 value for x and y, see constraint in problem

Comment: @sahasrara62, yea I accidentally didn't put `+ 1` to `range()`. Edited, tests are passed now

Comment: for aboove given input ( 4540, 312, 752) it is giving 4512, but it should be 4384

Comment: @sahasrara62, it's not told that you have to have at least one of each. It's their value at least 1, not their count

Comment: @sahasrara62, there is literally 2nd test named `One Type Needed`)

Comment: see constraint there in problem 1 <= a < b <5000, dont know aboout test case there, but constraint is pretty much clear there.

Comment: @sahasrara62 a and b are pills `mg`s, they are passed to function directly and not changed. However `x` and `y` mean count of pills and may be 0, there is no constraint for that.

Comment: here  1 <= a < b <5000 means that no of  a type of pills is from [1, 5000) and and for b typoe of pills it is also [1, 5000) so which restrain minimum no of a, b type  of pill be atleast 1, so no case where one can take them 0 .

Comment: a and b are strength of pills, not their amount, that means that there can be 0 pills with strength a/b

Comment: OP has accepted this as soluition,  cool happy, lets end this discussion

Comment: Thank you, so from what I could understand you iterated i from 0 to the maximum possible value of dividing d by a, then multiplied that with a and minused from d in order to get the total range of values of d, and then just minused d from the minimim of that range to find the maximum value of d representable. This might be confusing but I think I got it. My only question is that what is the purpose in doing a + 1? Why not directly a?

Comment: @Sh4dy, `+1` goes apart from a (math operator priority) and needed to range() function include the boundary value if d is divisible by a. What i mean is if d is 10 and a is 2 then d // a is 5. range will build range object with [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] values inside. But clearly the nearest answer will be a * 5  + b * 0 = 10. But 5 is not in range values, that's why I +1 d // a ( 5 + 1, 6 in total)